# Zapier Python editor doesn't output anything even though code works in python

Tags: python, checkbox, zapier, webflow

I'm trying to create code that matches True/False messages from checkboxes from a form to the checkbox titles. Whenever the checkboxes are clicked, the titles should be appended to a list that is outputted in the end.

This is my code:

```py
def nische(input_data):
    nischen = []
    for key in input_data:
        if input_data[key] == True:
            print(key)
            nischen.append(key)
        if input_data['Sonstiges'] != "":
            nischen.append(input_data['Sonstiges'])
    string = ', '.join(nischen)
    string = str(string)
    return string

result = nische(input_data)
output = print(result)
```

​I've tried everything, but the Zapier Interpreter shows no output.

[this is the zapier output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l47Hr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESXAX.png)
​
​

​
​

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the last line: `output = print(result)`.

The `print` function doesn't return anything (it just prints), so your `output` is `None`.

Instead, return your result:

```py
return {'result': result}
```

(output must be a `dict`, not a string)